# Two for each loops for a query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to make a loop for 2 arrays and I run into conflicts where it creates duplicate entries...I figure I am just creating the loop wrong.

```
        foreach($productIds as $productID){

            foreach($qty as $q) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderedProducts (productID, orderID, qty) VALUES 
((select productID from products where productID ='$productID'), '$orderID', '$q')";
           execute_query($sql);

                 }
           }
```

If I remove the qty loop and just hardcode the qty in it works fine. Is there some sort of way  to combine the two loops?

Comment: if you echo $sql with qty loop what are you getting ;; ?

Comment: With or without the productIDs loop?

Comment: with productIds loop ..

Comment: INSERT INTO orderedProducts (productID, orderID, qty) VALUES ((select productID from products where productID ='1'), '24', '1000')Error updating database: Duplicate entry '1-24' for key 'PRIMARY'

Basically the productID may not be duplicated in the table. The orderID can.

Comment: The products do not have duplicates in the array...$productIds = array("1","2","3");

Comment: there is no duplicacy but when you try to run it with second loop it will create problem... because assume $qty = array("1","2") so insert will be run twice for each product id causing the duplicate insertion

Comment: Ahh, yes. Any ideas on how I should go about fixing it?

Comment: I have tried to give a solution.. hope it gives you some idea

Comment: Ohh I didnt realised that .. what is your primary key in orderedProducts.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem...can't use foreach loops it just messes up, I just used the index's of the arrays

```
    for($i =0 ; $i < sizeof($productIds);$i++){ 
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderedProducts (productID, orderID, qty) VALUES ((select productID from products where productID ='$productIds[$i]'), '$orderID', '$qty[$i]')";
        execute_query($sql);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement on this,

```
INSERT INTO orderedProducts (productID, orderID, qty) 
SELECT productID, '$orderID', '$q'
FROM   products
WHERE  productID = '$productID'
```

- [INSERT INTO... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Completely offline system, not worried about that.

Comment: btw, same issue, Error updating database: Duplicate entry '1-23' for key 'PRIMARY'....The productID can not be duplicated.

Comment: it because there may have been multiple `productID` on table `products`. What exactly do you want on table `orderedProducts`?

Comment: The array for productIDs is $productIds = array("1","2","3");

No chance there are duplicates. But for some reason it loops through trying to add 1 again.